# Extract number from the end of a string

Tags: string, split, lua

I have strings with pattern "ab234cafsd5464". I need to extract last part of the string which is a number. How do we do this in Lua?

Comment: Learn more about lua patterns: http://anchorshttps://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:understanding_lua_patterns such as the symbols used as  see Tim's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform an anchored match from the end of the string of one or more digits:

```
string.match("ab234cafsd5464", "%d+$")
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to extract the initial part?

Comment: @anglee `"%a(%d+)%a"`

Comment: this returns nil. I need to still search from the end but instead of returning the match, I need the remaining part. Maybe I should use, string.split() ?

Comment: @anglee `for numbers in string.gmatch("ab234cafsd5464", "%d+") do print(numbers) end` this will find all runs of digits in a given string

Comment: @Nifim, sorry; I just need this string split into 2. "ab234cafsd" and "5464". These two have specific meanings.

Comment: @anglee split: `a,b = string.match("ab234cafsd5464", "(.-)(%d+)$")`